# How to allow a function sortbydate() when I'm Observable.interval

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, substitution

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "StatusCode": 0,
    "StatusMessage": "OK",
    "StatusDescription": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "datetime_device": "2018-05-11 12:05:00",
            "client_name": "Client1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "datetime_device": "2018-05-11 12:05:00",
            "client_name": "Client1"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "datetime_device": "2018-04-11 12:05:00",
            "client_name": "Client1"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "datetime_device": "2018-01-11 12:05:00",
            "client_name": "Client1"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "datetime_device": "2018-02-11 12:05:00",
            "client_name": "Client2"
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "datetime_device": "2018-01-05 12:05:00",
            "client_name": "Client2"
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "datetime_device": "2018-05-09 12:05:00",
            "client_name": "Client1"
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "datetime_device": "2018-05-01 12:05:00",
            "client_name": "Client1"
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "datetime_device": "2018-01-01 12:01:00",
            "client_name": "Client1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I create a function that sort by date this JSON.

```
  private getTime(date?: Date) {
    return date != null ? date.getTime() : 0;
  }
  public sortbydate(): any[] {
    return this.notification0.sort((a, b) => {
      return this.getTime(new Date(a.datetime_device)) - this.getTime(new Date(b.datetime_device));
    }
    );
  }
```

In html:

```
  <div class="input-field col s2">
      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (click)="sortbydate()">Time</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
```

**up to here it works very well**

Now, I used a function, that call  in interval 10000 this function. `this.getallnotif();`

```
 public notification: Notifications[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = Observable.interval(10000).subscribe(x => {
      this.getallnotif();
    });

  getallnotif() {
    this.ws.notif().subscribe(
      notification => {
        console.log(notification)
        this.notification = notification;
      }
    );
  }
```

service.ts

```
  public notif(): Observable<Notifications[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.notif), {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
          this.auth.logout();
        } else{
          return res.StatusDescription.map(notiff => {
            return new Notifications(notiff);
          });
        }

      });
  }
```

This code currently works, events are called in this interval, and the order function, sort the dates in order. When I click the sortbydate () button, my data are properly sorted, but only for a time interval of 10000. I want my data to stay sorted after this interval.

Please have any idea how can I do this?

Update:

I tried this code

```
 this.subscription = Observable.interval(10000).subscribe(x => {
    let notification = this.sortbydate();
    if (x >= notification.length) {
      x = notification.length
         }
         console.log(notification0[x]) // data are all of time sorted but new events not show, only when I refresh page. Please any idea why?
         return notification0[x]
     });
```

Comment: Can you maybe reword this? "But what I have to do is that the order by date does not break at the time of the interval. It is necessary that when the button is clicked to not break the order, only the event will appear on the scheduled date." I really can't understand what you are saying.

Comment: When I click the `sortbydate ()` button, my data are properly sorted, but only for a time interval of 10000. I want my data to stay sorted after this interval.

Comment: It looks like every 10000 ms you are getting a new copy of `this.notification` which would render in your template not sorted by date. You probably should hold onto a variable on your component stating that the notifications are sorted by date and use that when you are setting the new notifications. You can check at that point if it is supposed to be sorted by date and call the method to sort

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Yes, I tried something, like in update post, but now, my new notifications not show in page. Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a variable to hold onto how the notifications are sorted. If you have more than just date, you'll need to do something else besides this simple example.

```
isSortedByDate = false;
```

Then when you click your button to sort you'll want to set that property to `true`.

```
public sortbydate() {
    this.isSortedByDate = true;

    this.notification.sort((a, b) => {
        return this.getTime(new Date(a.datetime_device)) - this.getTime(new Date(b.datetime_device));
    });
}
```

Then when you are getting your new notifications you'll want to check this property and sort.

```
this.ws.notif().subscribe(notification => {
    console.log(notification)
    this.notification = notification;

    if (this.isSortedByDate) {
        this.sortbydate();
    }
});
```

On a different note, it is considered an anti-pattern to have a `subscribe` nested within a `subscribe` in rxjs. You could accomplish your same thing without that second `subscribe`. In fact it would be best if you didn't use any `subscribe`s so you don't have to take care of unsubscribing (using the async pipe):

```
private isSorted = false;
private notificationsSubject$ = new Subject<Notifications[]>();
notifications$ = this.getNotifications();

private getNotifications(): Observable<Notifications[]> {
    return Observable.interval(10000)
        .concatMap(() => this.ws.notif())
        .merge(this.notificationsSubject$)
        .map(notifications => this.isSorted ? this.sort(notifications) : notifications);
}

private sort(notifications: Notifications[]): Notifications[] {
    return [...notifications].sort((a, b) => {
        return this.getTime(new Date(a.datetime_device)) - this.getTime(new Date(b.datetime_device));
    });
}

sortByDate(notifications: Notifications[]) {
    this.isSorted = true;
    this.notificationsSubject$.next(notifications);
}
```

Then in your template where you are currently looping over the notifications, you will need to use the `async` pipe. You can add an `<ng-template>` so you can hold onto the reference of the notifications for the sort method using an `*ngIf` like so:

```
<ng-template *ngIf="notifications$ | async as notifications">
    <divOrWhateverYouHave *ngFor="let notification of notifications"></divOrWhateverYouHave>
    <div class="input-field col s2">
        <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (click)="sortByDate(notifications)">Time</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

I put together a [StackBlitz to show all of this working together](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-notification-sorting).